# Optimization warning in gcc12

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm porting a project from gcc10 (debian bullseye) to gcc12 (debian bookworm). But this minimal code is causing problems:

```
// compile with `g++ -O3 -Werror`
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<int PAD> std::vector<uint8_t> paddedString(const std::string& src)
{
    int size = std::max<int>(src.size() + 1, PAD);
    std::vector<uint8_t> res(size % PAD == 0 ? size : size + (PAD - (size % PAD)));
    std::fill(res.begin(), res.end(), 'x');
    std::copy(src.begin(), src.end(), res.begin());
    return res;
}

int foo()
{
    auto s1 = paddedString<4>("123");   // "123x"
    auto s2 = paddedString<4>("12345"); // "12345xxx"
    auto s3 = paddedString<4>("1234");  // "1234xxxx"
    auto s4 = paddedString<1>("1234");  // "1234x"     <-- error here
    return 0;
}
```

In GCC 10, this code compiles fine, but in GCC 12 I get the following error from the `std::copy(...)` invoked in the `s4 =`  line.

> error: writing 1 byte into a region of size 0

Full message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12/string:50,
                 from paddedString.cpp:1:
In static member function ‘static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const char*; _OI = unsigned char*]’,
    inlined from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const char*; _OI = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:495:30,
    inlined from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a1(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const char*; _OI = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:522:42,
    inlined from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, __cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, vector<unsigned char> >]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:529:31,
    inlined from ‘_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, __cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, vector<unsigned char> >]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:620:7,
    inlined from ‘std::vector<unsigned char> paddedString(const std::string&) [with int PAD = 1]’ at paddedString.cpp:9:14,
    inlined from ‘int foo()’ at paddedString.cpp:18:37:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:385:25: error: writing 1 byte into a region of size 0 [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
  385 |               *__result = *__first;
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12/string:41:
In member function ‘_Tp* std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::allocate(size_type, const void*) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’,
    inlined from ‘static _Tp* std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocate(allocator_type&, size_type) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/alloc_traits.h:464:28,
    inlined from ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:378:33,
    inlined from ‘void std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_create_storage(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:395:44,
    inlined from ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Vector_base(std::size_t, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:332:26,
    inlined from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(size_type, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:552:47,
    inlined from ‘std::vector<unsigned char> paddedString(const std::string&) [with int PAD = 1]’ at paddedString.cpp:7:26,
    inlined from ‘int foo()’ at paddedString.cpp:18:37:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset [21, 9223372036854775797] into destination object of size 5 allocated by ‘operator new’
  137 |         return static_cast<_Tp*>(_GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
      |                                                       ^
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset 5 into destination object of size 5 allocated by ‘operator new’
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset [21, 9223372036854775797] into destination object of size 5 allocated by ‘operator new’
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset 5 into destination object of size 5 allocated by ‘operator new’
In static member function ‘static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const char*; _OI = unsigned char*]’,
    inlined from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const char*; _OI = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:495:30,
    inlined from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a1(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const char*; _OI = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:522:42,
    inlined from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, __cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, vector<unsigned char> >]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:529:31,
    inlined from ‘_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, __cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, vector<unsigned char> >]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:620:7,
    inlined from ‘std::vector<unsigned char> paddedString(const std::string&) [with int PAD = 1]’ at paddedString.cpp:9:14,
    inlined from ‘int foo()’ at paddedString.cpp:18:37:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:385:25: error: writing 1 byte into a region of size 0 [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
  385 |               *__result = *__first;
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In member function ‘_Tp* std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::allocate(size_type, const void*) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’,
    inlined from ‘static _Tp* std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocate(allocator_type&, size_type) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/alloc_traits.h:464:28,
    inlined from ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:378:33,
    inlined from ‘void std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_create_storage(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:395:44,
    inlined from ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Vector_base(std::size_t, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:332:26,
    inlined from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(size_type, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:552:47,
    inlined from ‘std::vector<unsigned char> paddedString(const std::string&) [with int PAD = 1]’ at paddedString.cpp:7:26,
    inlined from ‘int foo()’ at paddedString.cpp:18:37:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset [22, 9223372036854775798] into destination object of size 5 allocated by ‘operator new’
  137 |         return static_cast<_Tp*>(_GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
      |                                                       ^
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset 6 into destination object of size 5 allocated by ‘operator new’
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset [22, 9223372036854775798] into destination object of size 5 allocated by ‘operator new’
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset 6 into destination object of size 5 allocated by ‘operator new’
```

The error goes away if:

- I go back to gcc10
- I comment out the lines above (`s1` through `s3`)
- PAD is set to something other than 1, 2, 3, 5, or 6  (4, 7, 8+: no issue)
- I use `-02` or lower
- I rename `foo()` to `main()`
- I compile with `-Wno-error=stringop-overflow`

I don't really like any of those options.

The error remains, even if I replace `std::copy(...)` with:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < src.size(); ++i) 
    res[i] = src[i];
```

What's going on?

---

Edit: If I add `int main() { return foo(); }`, and compile with `-O3 -Wno-stringop-overflow`, `valgrind` seems happy:

```
$ valgrind -s ./a.out 
==2558187== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2558187== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2558187== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2558187== Command: ./a.out
==2558187== 
==2558187== 
==2558187== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2558187==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2558187==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 72,729 bytes allocated
==2558187== 
==2558187== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2558187== 
==2558187== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Still happens in 13.2. I would search for a GCC bug and file one with the minimal example you have here. And then suppress the stringop-overflow warning for this function.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106297 <- maybe this one? (something about loop unrolling)

Comment: Given that it's even hitting the linux kernel, i'd say it's likely a GCC bug: https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-Drop-GCC--Wstringop-of

Comment: If it's a compiler bug, I'm happy to ignore as long as it's just a false-positive and not an indication of bad machine-code generation.  Is that the case?

Comment: Overstepping the bounds on a vector is something valgrind and address sanitizer should catch. Try both?

Comment: `valgrind` is happy with this code.

Comment: had to add `#include <cstdint>` https://godbolt.org/z/1cEKjd89o

Comment: address sanitizer also seems happy.

Comment: So it's likely to be a problem with the warning and the solution is to silence it as Linux did.